# How to filter folder children using cmis query?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I would like to filter the children of folders from a cmis 1.0 compliant repository with one query. So far that doesn't seem to be possible so I have settled to execute two queries to retrieve the children (i.e. folders and documents), however would still like to filter children by custom types so I have the following query:

```
SELECT cmis:objectTypeId, cmis:objectId FROM cmis:folder WHERE cmis:objectTypeId = 'my:custom1' OR cmis:objectTypeId = 'my:custom2' OR cmis:objectTypeId = 'cmis:folder' IN_FOLDER('workspace://SpacesStore/fhj738tw-45hW-659u-9DS1-9cX3Nh95r089')
```

Which doesn't work as I keep getting an error about mismatched input.

Comment: if i understand your question you need it to get the children of one particular folder ?!?

Comment: The question is 2 parts. First to be able to retrieve all the children of a folder  in one query (doesn't seem possible far as I can tell) and second to filter the results of what's returned such that only arbitral types specified (i.e. cmis:objectTypeId = my:type) are returned.

Comment: I assure you that my example worked fine, i will update my answer to get it with a type

Comment: @YagamiLight I have tried and haven't come up with a way to get the arbitral types from within a folder with one query, especially since I am restricted to CMIS 1.0. I think 1.1 has the possibility to retrieve children by leveraging cmis:item but this I do not know, and can't test as of now.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this query in order to get children of a particular `folder`

```
String query;
query = "SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE IN_FOLDER('" + folderId + "')";
```

and to get all the children

```
ItemIterable<QueryResult> resultList = session.query(query, false);// No need to say about session ???
```

and finally

```
for (QueryResult qr : resultList) {

String idDocument = qr.getPropertyByQueryName("cmis:objectId").getFirstValue().toString();
Document doc = (Document) session.getObject(idDocument);

}
```

Note that in my example i only get `cmis:objectId` you can get more from [Cmis Query](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Query_Language)

Hope that will help you.

Comment: I more or less did this. I was just wondering whether it is possible to filter the result I retrieve via query. but I am doing that post retrieval now. Thanks

Comment: @DarkStar1 please note that in my example i only get `cmis:objectId` you can get more https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Query_Language

Comment: I already know this. I was asking for something that I haven't found examples to

Comment: @DarkStar1 read this very interesting post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468515/how-to-do-mass-update-in-alfresco-using-cmis