# Search for multi-value all

Tags: search, cmis

CMIS search is there a way to search for all

In SQL it would be

```
select ID 
from mvTo
where name in ('john', 'sally', 'same') 
group by ID 
having count(*) = 3
```

assume unique index on name

Comment: please read this two posts it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458669/how-to-filter-folder-children-using-cmis-query/39467372#39467372 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468515/how-to-do-mass-update-in-alfresco-using-cmis/39470100#39470100

Comment: This link states having is not supported   https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5898-cmis-query-language

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single-value property, such as cmis:createdBy, you can write a query that matches on any value in a list, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document where cmis:createdBy in ('jpotts', 'admin', 'tuser1')
```

If you have a multi-value property, and you want to match if any of the values match, you can use the ANY keyword, like:

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document where ANY sc:someMultiValuedProp in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

Group by is not supported.

For more information on what you can do with CMIS queries, read the Query Language Definition section of the [CMIS specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.pdf).

Comment: Any is not All.   Is the away to search for 'val1' and  'val2' and 'val3'

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: In Alfresco 4.0.e combining ANDs this works for me: SELECT F.* FROM  cmis:folder F WHERE F.ns:somemvprop='val1' AND F.ns:somemvprop='val2' AND F.ns:somemvprop='val3'